# Connecting to a WAN server in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I was wondering if it was possible to connect to a listening server that is not on the LAN but instead on the WAN. What changes would I have to make to allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LAN, MAN and WAN are relative terms used to describe the size of a network; they relate to the hardware layout.  Hardware is intentionally transparent to socket programming.  So there's no need to concern yourself with these items.

If you do have difficulty connecting look into: 
NAT/Firewalls:  They block stuff
Routing: particularly subnets and private ip's.
Telnet: A fairly simple way to see if you can connect to a TCP server on the net is just try to telnet into it.

AFA programmatic testing, I recommend a simple [chat application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx).  Its a great learning tool for beginners.  I like to use a working socket application before writing a new one in order to work out all the network kinks prior to development.

Answer (score 2):

If there's nothing blocking the connection between you and the WAN server, just change the address you're connecting to. The Internet Protocol is the same, no matter what the network size is.